# Different shape of parentheses

Tags: math-mode, formatting, typography

While correcting a thesis of a colleague I found this:

[image: screenshot of parentheses, relevant source code highlighted]

As you can see, the parentheses around the first and the second item differ, however, they're implemented in the exact same manner (see code snippet and highlighted source code respectively).

```
\begin{equation}
\left( p+\frac{a\rho ^2}{N^2_{A}} \right) \left(1-\frac{\rho}{N_{a}}b \right) = \frac{\rho}{N_{a}}R\vartheta
\end{equation}
```

Can anyone explain how they come to look different? Is it because of the indices and exponents?

Comment: Using a standard class and `amsmath` package, I can't confirm the difference between the parentheses. We need more information

Comment: `amsmath` and `amssymb` is used here and the standard class `scrreprt`. Font package `kpfonts`.

Comment: `kpfonts` presumably being the decisive information, that's why it's always best to post a complete (small) document that demonstrates the effect, rather than a fragment which may or may not depending on what other code is needed.

Comment: You're right, I just forgot to mention the font package in my post... :/ Anyways, I accept your answer below.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Actually,I know that already. This time it slipped in, it seems. :-P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TeX fonts have a certain number of delimiters in a range of sizes, and then at some point they switch to a scheme that uses a repeatable straight section to make delimiters of arbitrary size. You just happened to hit the tipping point where one delimiter is a fraction over the point at which it switches to the extendable section. Different font sets will switch at different points, depending how many designed delimiter sizes the font has.

Comment: This is what I expected... In this specific case it would be the best to choose the size manually via \big( etc, I guess?

Comment: @LCsa `\bigl(....\bigr)` with `l` and `r` but yes choosing a size manually is probably the easiest thing here (and often improves the horizontal spacing anyway)